# How to Reload a JFrame - Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am programming in java and I want to refresh my `Jframe` and change the color through loop, but I can't reload the frame but I can only create a new one.

```
package frames;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame1 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int num = 0;



    while (num<255)
    {
        num +=1;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(num,num,num));
        frame.setTitle("");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call JFrame#invalidate() and then JFrame#validate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You only need to use one frame (you are creating 255 of them)
2. Don't use a while loop to try and change the background. Use a Swing Timer instead. See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
3. Run all your Swing apps on the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Here's your code refactored with those three points

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Frame1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(
                        new Color(0, 0, 0));
                Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                    int num = 0;
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (num > 255) {
                            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                        } else {
                            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(
                                    new Color(num, num, num));
                            num++;
                        }
                    }
                });
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, there will be only one frame created and you adapt the color and make your desired refresh.

```
package frames;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame1 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int num = 0;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setTitle("");

    while (num<255)
    {
        num +=1;

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
         // Here, we can safely update the GUI
         // because we'll be called from the
         // event dispatch thread
          frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(num,num,num));
          frame.pack();
          frame.repaint();
         }
        }
}
  });


    }
}
}
```

Maybe I just mixed up the } but you should get an Idea how this should be done